# how to create a open/goto button linked to drop-down list

Tags: excel

I have an excel workbook with multi sheets inside where the sheets named like (1,2,3,..10). In the dashboard sheet, I created a drop-down list (involve the names of the sheets) with a button.
how can I link the button to open a specific sheet based on what I chose from the drop-down list?

in a simple way.. if I chose number(1) from the drop-down list and hit the button, it will take me to the sheet named (1).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Say the drop-down is in cell **B9**.  Put some `Shape` on the worksheet and assign this macro to it:

```
Sub Leap()
    Dim s As String
    s = CStr(Range("B9"))
    Sheets(s).Activate
End Sub
```

**Note:**

We convert possible numbers into strings